# WCF Publish Subscribe Design

Tags: wcf, publish-subscribe

We've implemented a list based publish subscribe based on the MSDN article. However, there are a few scenarios that I wanted covered in the design.

1. I read that it is a good practice to denotify once the notification occurs. But in our scenario, this needs to be notified every time there is a change. So should I go ahead and denotify and subscribe again after all the subcsribers have denotified themselves?
2. What happens if my publisher goes down? Is there some way where I can get the publisher back to the state with all the subscribers intact? This is a critical scenario since we will have many subscribers and we dont want to fail to notify them
3. Failure to notify: How can we know if a subscriber has not received the  notification and how can we handle this
4. Anything else that I might need to cover in the design?

Appreciate your help

-Soni

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx

Comment: suggest you use Nservicebus rather than writing your own WCF based service.

Comment: I did read a little about it but will these concerns be addressed by it? and why cant we design our solution on the same lines? There is an associated cost with it as well.

Comment: will your hand  rolled solution be as good as something tried and tested by many people?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion Mitch.
We have gone ahead with this framework by the IDesign folks
http://www.idesign.net/Downloads

Look for Publish Subscribe Framework.
It takes some time to understand the code but its pretty neat!